# Mongo Spring Data "foreign" key

Tags: java, json, spring, mongodb

I'm using [Spring Data](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/mongodb) to manage my MongoDB database.

On one collection I have 2 ObjectId fields, _id and one other that references an instance from another collection.

My collection's class is like:

```
public class CollectionA
{
private ObjectId id;
private String collectionADescription
private ObjectId collectionBId
}
```

with the class specified like this I am able to insert the "foreign key" sucessfully as an $oid.

The problem is that I am getting the following binding error:

> Field error in object 'collectionA' on field 'collectionBId': rejected
>   value []; codes
>   [typeMismatch.collectionA.collectionBId,typeMismatch.collectionBId,typeMismatch.org.bson.types.ObjectId,typeMismatch];
>   arguments
>   [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable:
>   codes [collectionA.collectionBId,collectionBId]; arguments []; default
>   message [collectionBId]]; default message [Failed to convert property
>   value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'org.bson.types.ObjectId' for property 'collectionBId'; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of
>   type [java.lang.String] to required type [org.bson.types.ObjectId] for
>   property 'collectionBId': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found]

If I set the collectionBId variable to String the variables are inserted as string instead of $oid

How can I accomplish this?

Thans

Answer (score 2):

If you really want relations in your datastore, you should use Spring Data MongoDB [@DBRef](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/mapping-chapter.html#mapping-usage-references) annotations. But I recommend you reconsider/redesign your schema in favor of using embedded documents. Maybe [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/) document will help you to design better schema.